# Summing a single column in attributes table QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to sum up all of the values of a single column in QGIS3.4. I found some instruction on how to do this using the statistics panel, however, when I select the column I need to sum no values show up (see image). All the values in the column are numerical integers. I don't know if there's something wrong with my computer not playing nice with QGIS or if this tool is not working as it's supposed to (personally I'm assuming operator error).

[image: Statistics panel]

Comment: The box for "selected features only" is checked. Do you have any features selected?

Comment: I did not, when I unchecked that it worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I posted my suggestion as an answer. You can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way others with the same issue will see which solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in tool `Show statistical summary` and select the layer and the field you want. It will show all the statistics including the summation of all values if there are no selected features:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, I can see that the box for "Selected features only" is checked. When this box is checked, the tool only summarized selected features. If no features are selected, no summary value is calculated.

Un-check the box next to "Selected features only" to see a value summary for all features in the layer.